# Script for automatic turn ON/OFF git proxy (ECLIPSE)

Tags: eclipse, git, bash, proxy

I am quite beaten of turning ON/OFF the proxies every time I get home from University.

Moreover, I use Ubuntu, so the number of proxies I have to change are more. But I would specifically like to get an automatic way to turn ON/OFF the Egit proxy settings.

So, **is there an automatic way to get executed bash commands**, just clicking on a file?

Answer (score 0):

Install this tool: [gsettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) and set a script with those entries

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host <host url>
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port <port>
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'

# to disable proxy:
# gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
```

For a complete list of options to set checkout this link:
https://developer.gnome.org/ProxyConfiguration/